# I want limit type T that is a class which implements the Comparable<T> interface in a generic class

Tags: java

I defined a generic class `A<T>` in Java, but I want to limit the type `T` such that it is a class which implements the `Comparable<T>` interface. What should i do?

Answer (score 7):

I think you just want:

```
class A<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
}
```

Or possibly:

```
class A<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
{
}
```

The latter is slightly more flexible - it allows for things like:

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Object>
{
}

A<Foo> a = new A<Foo>();
```

That's fine if you just want `A` to be able to compare values of type `T`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class A<T extends Comparable<? super T>>{
...

}
```

this allows you to use subclasses of classes that implement comparable

Answer (score 0):

You can put an upper bound on `T`:

```
public class A<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A <T implements ComparableInterface>
```